# SOLR 8.1.1 EdgeNGramFilterFactory parsing query

Tags: apache, solr, tokenize

I have a SOLR 4.10.2 core, and I am upgrading to 8.1.1.

I created an 8.1.1 core manually using the default_config set , and then brought over settings into the 8.1.1 schema.

I have adjusted the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml, and I have the core queryable in 8.1.1.

I have a field named Company:

```
<field name="Company" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="IDX_Company" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="Company" dest="IDX_Company"/>
```

In 4.10.2 when I run the query:

IDX_Company:blue

with debugQuery on, I see the query parsed into pieces (correctly)

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "IDX_Company:blue",
    "querystring": "IDX_Company:blue",
    "parsedquery": "(IDX_Company:b IDX_Company:bl IDX_Company:blu IDX_Company:blue)/no_coord",
```

...

When I run this against 8.1.1, with debugQuery on, I get the following:

```
"debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"IDX_Company:blue",
    "querystring":"IDX_Company:blue",
    "parsedquery":"IDX_Company:blue",
```

...

It seems to not be applying the EdgeNGramFilterFactory - the only change I made to the EdgeNGramFilterFactory configuration was to remove the "side" attribute, per the documentation.
Also, per the documentation, I replaced the SynonymFilterFactory with SynonmGraphFilterFactory, and added the FlattenGraphFilterFactory.

I have tried removing the FlattenGraphFilterFactory, I have cleared and repopulated the core (reindexed), I have stopped and started SOLR 8.1.1, and no difference.

Here is the definition of text_general I am using in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/> <!-- RDH - removed side="front"-->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- RDH SynonymFilterFactory has been deprecated, replace with SynonymGraphFilterFactory -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> 
        <!-- RDH https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/filter-descriptions.html
            Flatten Graph Filter
            This filter must be included on INDEX-time analyzer specifications that include at least one graph-aware filter, including Synonym Graph Filter and Word Delimiter Graph Filter.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- strip all punctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{N} ]" replacement=" " replace="all" /> <!-- RDH -->
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/> <!-- RDH - removed side="front"-->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- RDH SynonymFilterFactory is deprecated, replace with SynonymGraphFilterFactory -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- RDH https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/filter-descriptions.html
            Flatten Graph Filter
            This filter must be included on INDEX-time analyzer specifications that include at least one graph-aware filter, including Synonym Graph Filter and Word Delimiter Graph Filter.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>  
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- strip all punctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{N} ]" replacement=" " replace="all" /> <!-- RDH -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Are you sure your field definition has been loaded at all? More recent versions of Solr has switched to the managed schema by default, so my guess is that the current schema used is not the one you've edited. The admin page in Solr should be able to tell you what the current, active definition of the field is (and the Analysis page will show you each step and the filter that is invoked).

Comment: @MatsLindh I can see the field in the schema browser,  i can query and see data in the field, so i know the field has been loaded with data. also checked in schema browser for text_general and it matches whats in schema.xml. ill  take a look at he analysis stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was reloading the information by clearing and posting the data into the core, I had neglected to go to the Core Admin page, choose the core, and click on the Reload button.

Now query is parsed as expected.